# IGBT H-bridge failure

Tags: h-bridge, igbt, shoot-through

I am using Infineon's IGBT - IKW50N65H5 and IKW50N65F5 for a H-bridge inverter. The DC supply to the inverter is the line supply of 230VAC with KBPC5010's full wave rectification. The bridge was being driven at 50kHz at 50% duty cycle so an ample dead-time of 5us. The bridge drives a 7.5kVA ferrite core transformer as its load.

[image]

In the schematic IGBT1 & 2 - IKW50N65H5

IGBT3 & 4 - IKW50N65F5

AC1 & AC2 are terminals to which the transformer is connected.

C7 - 2.2uF X rated at 305VAC and other electrolytics are 10uF

However, during testing with the secondary of ferrite transformer at no load, two IGBTs on one half of the H had a shoot-through resulting in shorting and the MCB (230V input) tripped. After removing the faulty IGBTs from the board, in IGBT2, the Gate-Collector and Emitter are all shorted (indicating some complete meltdown) while in IGBT3 the Collector-Emitter are alone shorted.

What are the possible causes of such a catastrophic shoot-through failure? What should I do to prevent them?

NOTE: Even if 50kHz is not typical IGBT frequency, Infineon's IKW50N family is specifically designed for this range.

Comment: Have you hooked this up to a scope.. without a load ... and current limited? What are the ACTUAL switching times of all that from source to switch?

Comment: What are the optical devices.. what are the mosfets.. what does 750E mean?

Comment: No, I didnt hook up the scope to the IGBT terminals as they are all high voltage and my scope cannot deal with it. But I compared the pulse at the gate to the logic pulse and there was nothing suspicious there - no delay.

Comment: The pmos is DMP3099L-7
The nmos is BSS316N H6327

Comment: The opto is TLP2745 and 750E means a 750 ohm resistor.

Comment: I guess I'm confused how you are wiring this.. It is not clear, what the voltages mean here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70318/discussion-between-hp07-and-trevor).

Answer (score 3):

The driver circuitry you have does not work the way you think it does. The top side drivers are not floating. They need to be isolated from each other and from the bottom side drivers in order to allow them to deviate up to your 325V supply level when they turn on.

Because of that the gate voltages will be exceeding their maximums and the gates will fail.

As such, if you want to use those driver circuits, you need something more like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9QL1O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[More readable version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQCVN.png)

In this circuit, the top-side drivers each have their own independent and floating 15V supply. The bottom side shares a third supply.

Also, your MOSFET driver uses the source follower mode. This means the gate voltage range is reduced by the threshold voltage of the MOSFETs. The circuit above corrects that, however, be aware that adds a logic inversion.

Comment: Assuming that this might be the fault, a high gate voltage that fried one of the IGBTs should have fried the gate driver as well right? After removing the faulty IGBTs, all other 4 drivers are intact.
Also the circuit initially worked at a low duty cycle of 5% without a hitch. I was able to see osscilations on the secondary of the transformer. The problem happened at 50% duty cycle switching.

Comment: @hp07 the problem is it will sort of work till it doesn't...

Answer (score -1):

international rectifier sells mosfet/igbt driver chips that come in many configurations. some are a single high and low side driver. 2 of these will make a full bridge driver.  their app notes are helpful.  good devices. good data sheets. google international rectifier mosfet driver chip.  digi key/mouser catalogs. microchip had some fast and powerful  drivers years ago. you probably want to limit speed to reduce spikes. use snubbers!

Comment: Answering actual OP question is always more helpful